# Cannot get rid of creation of mysql.log

Tags: mysql, logging

I have these settings in `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
...
disable_log_bin
general-log      = false
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysqld.general.log

long_query_time     = 1
slow_query_log      = false
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysqld.slow.query.log

[safe_mysqld]
log-error = /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log

[mysqld_multi]
...
log        = /var/log/mysql/mysqld_multi.log
```

Each time I start the MySQL server an empty file `/var/log/mysql.log` is created and it never gets filled.
I was searching in web for some solution but I don't find anything regarding the `mysql.log` as it seems to be outdated.

Can it be it's created by a *mistake*, again, as I don't find anything regarding `mysql.log` for MySQL 8.x or do you know how to avoid the creation?

I am running MySQL 8.0.20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted it in the [MySQL bug database](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99748) and got an answer:

Adding `log-error = /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log` in the `[mysqld]` section in the file `my.cnf` creates `mysql.log` in the directory I want to have.

However, I still don't understand why it remains empty when the above setting isn't mentioned.